# Projective conic generated by a set of tangent triangles.

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

I need to proof the following result:

Let C be a real projective conic and P, Q two points interiors to C then there
is another real projective conic such that every triangle inscribed on that conic with two of its sides passing throug P and Q respectively have their third side tangent to it.

(It might be useful to consider its dual version)

Can you think about any strategy to solve it?

Comment: What are "interior points" to a curve? Do you mean points on the curve?

Comment: I mean points from which you cannot draw any tangent to the conic (whereas from a point a conic you can draw only one and for a point "exterior" to a conic you can draw two)